# Which is the equivalent in Ruby to the Delphi SizeOf function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delphi

I want to get the number of bytes occupied by a variable or type in Ruby.  Is there an equivalent to the [`SizeOf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.SizeOf) function in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Equivalent to what? I'm assuming C.

Comment: Running out of virtual memory? :-)

Comment: Is this for debugging purposes or what? There is no such method in Ruby, so telling us what you want to accomplish might help people suggest a way to do it.

Comment: I am using SizeOf of Delphi to get the number of bytes in a variable, I also want to do this in my ruby application. thanks.

Comment: I'm really curious to know *why* you're needing to do this?

Comment: It just that, in my Delphi app, I used the SizeOf function as part of my encryption. And I have to do this set of codes in my Ruby app.

Answer (score 2):

As you see from the comments, there is no such method in Ruby. Since you can't manipulate the memory directly in Ruby and there are no explicit "simple" types (everything is an object), and due to the dynamic nature of Ruby, this method wouldn't be very useful anyway.

There is an exception of sorts with the `String` class. Since in Ruby a string is a sequence of bytes, `String#size` will return the size of the **data** in the string.

This should be sufficient for practical purposes, but it is **not** the number of bytes in memory - the String object will have other internal variables in addition to the data itself.

Also remember that all classes and objects can be modified dynamically in Ruby during runtime, which can change the amount of memory used. Just think of methods that add additional instance variables to an object that weren't there before.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to make things compatible with your Delphi code, than finding *Ruby's* sizes wouldn't help you at all. You need to take *Delphi's* sizes in your Ruby code. Since Delphi is statically typed, `SizeOf` is really a convenience - just make a table of the Delphi types and corresponding sizes. If you have an array, multiply the value from the table with the number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

The Scalar types are defined in ruby.c. I don't know of a way to learn their widths from within Ruby.

Added:

You could write a C program that uses ruby.c to determine the scalar sizes. Then call your C program from your Ruby sw.